# Identyfying prefix in the same string as a suffix

Tags: c, string

Eg-

maabcma is valid because it contains ma as a proper prefix as well as a proper suffix.
panaba is not.

How do I find out if a word is valid or not as above in C language?

I'm not very good at string operations. So, please help me out with a pseudocode.

Thanks in advance.

I'm completely lost. T=number of test cases.

EDIT: New code. My best code so far-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{

int i,T,flag=0;
int j,k,len=0;
char W[10],X[10];

scanf("%d",&T);

for(i=0;i<T;i++)
{
scanf("%s",W);

for(len=0;W[len]!='\0';len++)
X[len]=W[len];
X[len]='\0';


for(j=len-1;j>=0;j--)
for(k=0;k<len;k++)

{
if(X[k]!=W[j])
flag=0;

else if((j-k)==(len-1))
flag==1;

}


if (flag == 1)
printf("NICE\n");
else
printf("NOT\n");
}
}
```

Still not getting the proper results. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No. No one gonna help you. Simple rule on SO, first help your self.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Umm. Why? I've seen people going to great lengths to help each other out here. Because by doing so, they also learn one thing or another even if they are experts.

Comment: you need to learn c language , read book or search google

Comment: Get a book and start studying C

Comment: Please do look up what indentation is and how can you benefit from it.

Comment: You are setting the size of prefix nd suffix to 3 permanently?

Comment: **j is being used without being initialized**

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are only setting the value of flag if a match exists, otherwise you must set it to 0. because see, if I have:

`pammbap`

my prefix is `pam` and suffix is `bap`.

According to the final for loop,

`p` and `a` match so flag is set to `1`.

but when it comes to `b` and `m` it does not become zero. Hence, it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

First, `void` is not a valid return type for `main`, unless you are developing for [Plan 9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/comp.html).

Second, you should get into the habit of checking the return value of `scanf()` and all input functions in general. You can't rely on the value of `T` if the user does not input a number, because `T` is uninitialised. On that same note, you shouldn't use `scanf` with an *unbounded* `%s` scan operation. If the user enters 20 characters, this isn't going to fit into the ten character buffer that you have. An alternative approach is to use `fgets` to get a whole line of text at once, or, to use a *bounded* scan operation. If your array fits 10 characters (including the null terminator) then you can use `scanf("%9s", W)`.

Third, single-character variable names are often very hard to understand. Instead of `W`, use `word`, instead of `T`, use `testCount` or something similar. This means that someone looking at your code for the first time can more easily work out what each variable is used for.

Most importantly, think about the process in your head, and maybe jot it down on paper. How would you solve this problem yourself? As an example, starting with *n* = 1,

1. Take the first *n* characters from the string.
2. Compare it to the **last** *n* characters from the string
3. Do they match?

   1. If yes, print out the first *n* characters as the suffix and stop processing.
   2. If no, increment *n* and try again. Try until *n* is in the middle of the string.

There are a few other things to think about as well, do you want the *biggest* match? For example, in the input string `ababcdabab`, the prefix `ab` is also the suffix, but the same can be said about `abab`. In this case, you don't want to stop processing, you want to keep going even if you find a prefix, so, you should just store the *length* of the largest prefix that is also the suffix.

Second-most-importantly, running into hurdles like this is incredibly common when learning C, so don't let this put a dampener on your enthusiasm, just keep trying!

Comment: Thanks for trying to make me understand. But I'm really stuck. I know I'm very close. Please tell me where I'm wrong in my code.